# Difference between the old property declaration to the new way of declaration.

Tags: c#, .net

Previously people using this way to declare a property -

```
private int _idd;
        public int idd {
            get {
                return _idd;
            }
            set
            {
                _idd = value;
            }
```

But now a days they declare it this way - 
I am curious to know where is the private field goes and also how to use the advanced way to use this type of property. What is the private field of salary ? and Where the private field of salary ?

```
public int salary { set; get; }
```

How can i use this property - how to get and set this property.

Answer (score 1):

The "new" way is called Auto Property, the backing field is created by the CLR.

In your case of salary, the private field would be called _salary

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

> In C# 3.0 and later, auto-implemented properties make
>   property-declaration more concise when no additional logic is required
>   in the property accessors. They also enable client code to create
>   objects. When you declare a property as shown in the following
>   example, the compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field that
>   can only be accessed through the property's get and set accessors.

Answer (score 1):

They are called ['Auto-Implemented Properties'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx), introduced in C# 3.0. When you declare a property like this the compiler will automatically generate a private backing field for you.

You can use them just as any other property, you just have to get or set the *property* directly, rather than the field:

```
instance.salary = 100;
Console.WriteLine(instance.salary); // 100
```